# javascript code for overlaping <divs> in a table

Tags: javascript, css

I have a table with 2 rows and 3 columns; in each cell there is a div. 
What I want:

1. when mouse is over one div (say div1), I want to encrease its height and width (this is done)
2. the divs neighbours should remain still: no modification of left, top, right, bottom position.
3. the div1 overlaps over its neighbours

Can this be done ?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it can be done. You need to add z-index to the div which is currently active. So it will overlap the neighbour divs.

Comment: I added the zIndex for the active div, but this action only pushes the neighbours sideways... doesn't do the overlaping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with css only.
http://jsfiddle.net/Erp2B/

```
td { 
  position:relative;
  height:100px; 
  width:100px; 
  padding:5px; 
  background:#eee; 
  border:1px solid 
  #888;
}

td div { 
  position:absolute; 
  height:100px; 
  width:100px; 
  padding:5px; 
  top:0; 
  left:0;   
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
 }

td:hover div { 
  height:200px; 
  background:#f33; 
  z-index:1000; 
}
```

Comment: Sure...  at td:hover div {  ...  I added width:200px; ... and looks great.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to simply overlap then you can set the div to position: absolute. If you want it to overlap to the left/right/top/bottom then you'll want to give it a negative margin when hovering over it and increasing its width / height.